# Google mail for companies

Tags: g-suite, google

I worked for a Software company whose name was LVT. The company created a system in which every employee had as their email address something like *attilah@lvt.com* (instead of *attilah@gmail.com*) and we all were able to log in, share docs, etc.

So, what I'm asking is, How can I do the same? I don't know how it was done.

Answer (score 4):

Google will allow that.

https://www.google.com/a/

Comment: Thanks for fixing my URL. Thanks to google for not charging me for the service as a single user ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to buy Google Enterprise Apps - you can get the info directly from Google via http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html